# Unable to handle signals on Linux from inside of forked process

Tags: c, linux, signals, wait

I am trying to execute a fork function and use a signal handler in the child process, however when I run the program and try to send the signal the parent process gets the signal instead of the child process. The code:

```
 pid_t id = fork();
 if(id == 0)
 {
     struct sigaction ss;
     ss.sa_handler = &sigstop;
     sigaction(SIGTSTP, &ss, NULL);
     int status;
     status = execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
     if(status == -1)
         perror("MSH_ERROR (unknown command");
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
 else
 {
     wait(NULL);
 }
```

Comment: When you call `execvp` you are executing some other program, which is replacing yours. Including the signal handlers.

Comment: If you send a TSTP interactively (eg, with ^Z in a tty), the signal will be sent to all processes in the foreground process group.

Comment: Even though you're executing the same program in the child process, calling `execvp` will not retain signal handlers.